# Laravel: how to protect from trying to grab undefined property?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently getting this error : `{"status":0,"data":"Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::$special_id"}`

I am doing the following, which I thought would protect me from this error by only grabbing the property if the `$customer` exists.  The `User` table has `special_id` on it and it's initialized as `null`. :

```
        $customer = User::where('id', '=', $userId);

        $specialId = $customer ? $customer->special_id : null;

        if (empty($specialId)) {
            return;
        }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong though because it should only trying to be grabbing the property *if* `$customer` exists, based on the condition.

Comment: That's not how you get a model based on an id, try $customer =  User::find($userId);

Comment: You just miss the `first()` on your query,  as `$customer = User::where('id', '=', $userId)->first();`,  also you can use find() method  instead of that `$customer = User::find($userId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just miss the `first()` on your query :

```
$customer = User::where('id', '=', $userId)->first();
```

As alternative  you can use `find()` method :

```
$customer = User::find($userId);
```

Or, you can use `findOrFail()` method, this method will throw a 404 error if not match :

```
$customer = User::findOrFail($userId);
```

Comment: thanks, I just went with using `->first()` to the end of what i had

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple as this

```
$customer = User::findOrFail($id);

$specialId = ($customer) ? $customer->special_id : NULL;
```